# Fetch key value from string linux

Tags: linux, shell

I am doing:

```
dig  @example.com hostname.example.com | grep ANSWER:
```

which return me following output

```
;; flags: qr aa rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0
```

How can I use pipe to get the count of answer in variable.

```
var=$(dig  @example.com hostname.example.com | grep ANSWER:|....?...)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `awk` like this:

```
dig @8.8.8.8 www.example.com | awk '/ANSWER:/{print $2}' RS=,
```

The key here is to use `,` as the input record separator. Look how the input records appear to `awk` when using `RS=,`:

```
; <<>> DiG 9.10.3-P4-Ubuntu <<>> @8.8.8.8 www.example.com
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY
 status: NOERROR
 id: 49711
;; flags: qr rd ra ad; QUERY: 1
 ANSWER: 1       <----- Look here! The ANSWER: is a separate record
 AUTHORITY: 0
 ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0
 flags:; udp: 512
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;www.example.com.       IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
www.example.com.    74953   IN  A   93.184.216.34

;; Query time: 43 msec
;; SERVER: 8.8.8.8#53(8.8.8.8)
;; WHEN: Tue Jun 27 03:40:13 CEST 2017
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 60
```

The `ANSWER: N` section is a separate record. Now we can simply filter the `/ANSWER:/` record by regex and print the second column of that row using `print $2`.

---

PS: A `sed` alternative would be:

```
dig @8.8.8.8 www.example.com | sed -rn '/(.*ANSWER: )([0-9]+)(.*)/s//\2/p'
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `awk`. You can then loop through the columns, find the one with `ANSWER:`, and print the next column after it.

```
var=$(dig @example.com hostname.example.com | 
    awk '/ANSWER/ { for (i = 1; i < NF-1; i++) if ($i == "ANSWER:") { print $(i+1); break } }'
```

Comment: If you change `RS` to `,` it can be surprisingly simple. :) `awk '/ANSWER:/{print $2}' RS=,`